# Angular how to provide and overwrite a service with "useClass"?

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I have problems to "overwrite" a service with `provide: ... useClass: ...`.

There is a component `EditComponent` that uses a service `SettingsService`. See below:

```
@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SettingsService {
    public test: boolean = false;
}


@Component({
    selector: 'edit-reminders',
    templateUrl: './edit-reminders.component.html',
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
    //
    constructor ( private settingsService: SettingsService ) {
        console.log( '-----', this.settingsService )
    }
}
```

The component is registered and exported in a module in a pretty simple way, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EditComponent } from './edit.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [EditComponent],
    exports: [EditComponent]
})
export class EditModule {}
```

This `EditModule` module is now lazy loaded in a module (`ViewModule`) like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ViewComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit',
                loadChildren: () => import( '@app/edit.module' ).then( m => m.EditModule ),
            }
    }
]
```

So far everything works fine. But what I would need now is to "overwrite" the `SettingsService` with a different class. Therefore I tried to define in the `ViewModule`, something like

```
@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NewSettingsService {
    public test: boolean = true;
}


@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ViewComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: SettingsService, useClass: NewSettingsService }],
})
export class ViewModule {}
```

But this doesn't work. I don't get any error messages but the `NewSettingsService` is not used in the `EditModule`. Please can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can achieve that the `NewSettingsService` is applied in the `EditModule`?

Thnak you!